# Handling DataTable Column Name Mismatch Exception

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

i feeding my Data table from excel sheet upload,i face the problem when i look for a particular columns, ironically i don't know the position of column ,That can be anywhere or may be not present

so i cant Use indexing,when i go with column name then white spaces causing the problem

i assume the i know the index of Column but how can i handle the whitespaces

so far what i tried

**Code:**

---

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Columns[3].Caption.Replace(" ", "").Equals("XXXX"))
                {
                    var ds = from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() select new  { Fname=r.Field<String>("XX XX") , Lname=r.Field<string>(" Yy YY Y  ") };
                    ds.ToList();
                }
```

Do i need to care About the case sensitiveness in Column Name ?

how can i find the Column index if it matched with a given String ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the column like:

```
DataColumn yourColumn = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                    .Where(r => r.Caption.Trim().Equals("XXXX",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help, i found  alternative for this